# ios image processing software auto crop to borders

Tags: ios, image-processing, crop

I am implementing an application and my app needs to crop image based on background. I have seen similar behavior in document scanning applications where they automatically pick up image borders for crop. Can some one help me figure out how to achieve this functionality?

Disclaimer: I thought this might be an 'Askdifferent - Apple' question, but they sent me back to `SO`. So, if this doesn't belong, please let me know where to ask.

Update: Responding to the comment,
Here is what I have done until now:

- App launches the camera,
- sets the AVSession for viewfinder,
- preset to Photo, captures the images, saves to a file
- I am also creating small thumbnail previews for all images by compressing using CG API.
- Using AQGridView to display the images.

The goal is instead of compressing, I want 'auto cropped' images to be shown up in `AQGridview` to present a better user experience. Based on the nature of my app, it is pretty similar to receipt scanning as the subject may occupy only a small part of the image on a relatively clear background.
Hope it helps clarify..

Comment: You might want to show some type of effort on your part.  Also, if you are asking about the implementation of background subtraction, youre better off asking it here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Added more details and background..

Comment: I think that by "show some type of effort," scordova88 was suggesting that you tell us what you've tried so far in terms of implementing this auto crop feature. It's nice that you take the picture and create a thumbnail, but what have you tried in terms of figuring out where to crop the image? Other than mentioning something about the background, you haven't even told us what the criteria for deciding where to crop are.

Comment: That is exactly the problem I need to solve. I am not sure where to start as I have not much idea on image processing. Apple provides face detection but the problem is not face detection. I am trying to find if there is an algorithm based implementation that detects the image colors/contrast and gives the borders for crop.

Comment: @Caleb:I guess I misunderstood your question. Majority of the pictures are that of either documents or old pictures on a plain background. If document, I am looking for a plain rectangular color pattern. If Pictures, it is the same but search is on background pattern

Comment: @Kiran I am also looking for answer with exactly same requirement. please share if you found any solution on that

Answer (score 1):

A reasonably simple way to tackle that is to scan the image top to bottom and look at the profile of values in every row. While you are out of the printed area, you essentially see the background, i.e. the profile is quite flat, with high values (bright ones) slowly varying, plus noise fluctuations. When you meet printed features, the profile will show negative steps on at least one of the color components.

To detect them in a robust way, I would recommend to isolate strictly decreasing sequences of values and consider significant events when the total decrease reaches a given threshold. This will give you the topmost crop line. You can also reduce false detections by checking that the dark area following a decrease is long enough.

Repeat this starting from the bottom, and similarly from the left and the right.

Comment: I understand the logic. But I am looking for how to achieve it on iOS or atleast a reference to a similar implementation on a different platforms to see the details